# Azure AD using RSA MFA

Tags: azure-active-directory

Mi customer saw this article and asked if we have a more detailed documentation on how to make Azure AD uses the MFA from RSA instead of our own. Does anybody have guide on how to do it?

https://www.rsa.com/en-us/company/news/rsa-integrates-with-microsoft-azure-active-directory-for-two-factor-authentication

Regards,
Marcus Milhomem

The customer is a user of RSA and their security team prefer RSA over Azure MFA

I am really looking for a technical documentation on how to do this integration.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! This question is very likely to get closed because it isn't about programming. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for some more details. You might want to try asking over at https://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: (Also, did you try searching for this? A Google search for "rsa azure ad" gives me as the first result: https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-81278)

Answer (score 2):

There are two good places where you can leave document feedback and have the Azure AD team directly reply:

1. User Voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory
2. The other place is on the doc-issues themselves. This one might be an appropriate spot given that RSAs are mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/github-tutorial

I would strongly recommend leaving the feedback in user voice, since the product team monitors that feedback and adds it to their work items.

Hope this helps! If you make a request you can link it here and I can try to push it up to the product team and make a work item for it.